# kaminari automatically adds <ul> tag, how to make it to be <ol>?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I have tried adding `list-style-type: decimal` inside the CSS, but somehow it still didn't change. So I think the kaminari's paginate method cannot be forced by CSS. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Do you use gems like `bootstrap-kaminari-views` also?

Comment: See: https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari#to-edit-your-paginator